# Elasticsearch illegal mapping of a location array

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, mapping

I would like to perform geolocation queries with elasticsearch on my dataset which looks like this:

```
{"index": {"_index": "city","_type":"city_info", "_id":0} }
{"fields": { "city" : "AGAWAM", 
             "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], 
             "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA"},
             "id" : "01001" ,
             "type" : "add"}
...
```

I am able to perform a lot of queries or aggregates without any problems but when it comes to a query with a geodistance filter or anything working on geographic coordinates, it doesn't work. Here is my mapping test:

```
PUT /city/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "fields.loc": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [fields.loc] of different type, current_type [float], merged_type [geo_point]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [fields.loc] of different type, current_type [float], merged_type [geo_point]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

So it seems my "fields.loc" is a float whereas in the JSON it is an array with float values in. I tried to see what was the actual type of "loc" and it is indeed a float, which i don't understand why:

```
GET /city/_mapping
```

```
{
  "city" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "fields" : {
          "properties" : {
            "city" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "loc" : {
              "type" : "float"
...
```

So I don't understant, or rather I don't how to modify "loc" from a float to a geo_point.
As I am a beginner with elasticsearch, I am only using elasticsearch and kibana for cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the datatype implicitly to float (by bulk-syncing, as you probably did), it's gonna be difficult to convert the floats to geo_points.
I'd recommend dropping the index, setting the correct mapping with the `geo_point` datatype and resyncing everything.

In case you'd like to go deeper, have a look at the [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) api. Here's a [quick tut](https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/reindex-elasticsearch-documents-is-easier-than-ever-103f63d411c). That's something you'll probably face when your system runs in a production environment where dropping is now an option.

FYI, using a [custom _doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) type is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I've done the first thing you advised me: deleting the index, setting a new index with a correct mapping having "loc" type being "geo_point") and bulk-syncing again. Now my geo_distance query is working

Comment: Nice. Happy to help!